# CRM 2011 FetchXML returning invalid XML

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I am trying to retrieve an account but the fetchXML is returning invalid XML:

```
    function SelectLoadOutTransactionCurrency(id)
{
debugger;
var _oService = new FetchUtil(_sOrgName, _sServerUrl);
var sFetch = "<fetch mapping='logical'>" +
"<entity name='salesorder'>"+
"<attribute name='transactioncurrencyid' />" +
"<filter type='and'>" +
"<condition attribute = 'salesorderid' operator='eq' value='" + id + "'/>" +
"</filter>" +
"</entity>" +
"</fetch>";

var fetchResult =_oService.Fetch(sFetch, null);
return fetchResult.results[0].attributes["transactioncurrencyid"].guid;
}
 function GetSuppliers(){  
debugger;
_oService = new FetchUtil(_sOrgName, _sServerUrl);
var sFetch = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform'    mapping='logical' distinct='false'>" +
 "<entity name='account'>" +
 "<attribute name='name' />" +
 "<attribute name='accountid' />" +
 "<order attribute='name' descending='false'/>" +
 "<filter type='and'>" +
 "<condition attribute='new_accounttype' operator='eq' value='100000001'/>" +
 "</filter>" +
 "</entity>" +
 "</fetch>";        
 var fetchResult =_oService.Fetch(sFetch, null);
 return fetchResult;
 }
    function addOption(selectbox, text, value) {
        var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
        optn.text = text;
        optn.value = value;
        selectbox.options.add(optn);
    }
```

The name attribute has an invalid character (').. Is there a way to escape this character or is there an update rollup in place?

Comment: Your `_oService.Fetch` seems to convert the returned XML to an array of objects, it's probably bugged and doesn't handle the data properly. What's it like ?

Comment: You have 2 fetch statements, which one is erroring?  and like Alex asked - what is actually happening?  is fetchResult a string or array of objects?  does the code error out?  if so, what is the error message?

Comment: It returns an array - It errors on the function within the FetchUtil.

I will reply with more information a bit later today.